# Babel compilation error SyntaxError: Unexpected token when using spread operator

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using latest version of node but when i try using spread operator babel raise an 'unexpected' token even after i install @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

```
  Items = () => {
    return Item.find().then( items => {
        return items.map( item => {
            return {
                ...item._doc,
                 _id: item.id,
                date: new Date(item.date).toISOString()
            };
        })
    }).catch(e => {
        throw e
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To make support of spread operator you need to install `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin on your base project

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
// or 
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread --dev
```

and then create a .babelrc file in your project directory

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

if you have already then add this plugin like this

```
{
  "plugins": ["XXX", "YYY", .... ,"transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```